# oracle apex 5.1 error 500 Internal Server

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

Some times I use Oracle Apex and run some report, if my report takes a long time, The Apex gives an error and database locked.

error is **500 Internal Server Error**

I see Apex session in Database and the query is :

`SELECT ID, REPORT_TYPE FROM WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET_RPTS WHERE WORKSHEET_ID = :B5 AND APPLICATION_USER = :B4 AND (BASE_REPORT_ID = :B3 OR (NVL(:B3 ,0) = 0 AND NAME IS NULL)) AND SESSION_ID = :B2 AND SECURITY_GROUP_ID = :B1 FOR UPDATE`

what is that for? and do you know how to fix it?

Version Oracle:**11g** , Apex:**5.1.1**

Comment: Possibly something worth raising with Oracle Support.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp What is that mean? you mean some API in Apex doesn't work well? or some API didn't installed?

Comment: No, I mean it might be an issue you need to raise with Oracle Support. At the moment there's insufficient information to indicate if there is a particular problem with your instance, or why you are getting http 500.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp If my report getting a long time and other user click the same report when the previous report still working, I think it make a concurrency and makes the database lock.